# How to play HTML5 Video from a source other than same directory

Tags: directory, html5-video

I'm trying to play a video with the following html5:

```
<video src="/Users/user1/movie.m4v" controls="controls">
</video>
```

This will not play my video.

If I put the movie.m4v file in the same directory as the html file, it plays no problem.  Like this:

```
<video src="movie.m4v" controls="controls">
</video>
```

I'm sure this is a permissions thing, but how do I access this movie file outside the webserver directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browser simply concatenates current directory with whatever you write in the src tag - same way as <img> works.

So, if your code resides in `www.mysite.com/index.html` the latter snippet will result in request to `www.mysite.com/movie.m4v`, while the former one will ask web server for `www.mysite.com/Users/user1/movie.m4v`. You have to make sure that you can access the file from the web browser simply navigating to the address. If it works there, it will work in video tag too.

Comment: the file is not in the web server.  It is a local directory on the machine that has a web server.  It would never be able to be accessed like this.

Comment: If you intend to put the HTML file on a web server, then the movie too must be on the web server.

Answer (score 1):

src="/Users/user1/movie.m4v" translates into c:/Users/user1/movie.m4v on your local c drive. if movie.m4v is in a directory under the directory that index.html is in src needs to read like this src="Users/user1/movie.m4v"

On the website src="/Users/user1/movie.m4v" translates to http://thesite.com/Users/user1/movie.m4v Note the upper case "U" apache servers are case sensitive when running under linux.

You can also code the tag to the address on the server and open the html from your local drive ...

```
<video src="http://yourserver.com/Users/user1/movie.m4v" controls="controls">
</video>
```

... I assume you need to edit the page locally and view the results.